# Have we met a certain entity in Supernatural?

Tags: character-identification, supernatural

So, I've been rewatching Supernatural, and I saw something which made me wonder.  In the episode "Swan Song",

> Carver Edlund disappears at the end.

This got me thinking,

> is Carver representing God?

Supporting evidence includes:

1. > When Sam and Dean first met Carver, one of the first phrases out of his mouth was, "I'm God!"
2. > When Sam and Dean talked to Joshua, he said that God is down on Earth.
3. > He disappears, seemingly under his own volition, at the end of "Swan Song"

Anyone have any other evidence pro/con? Am I just overreaching? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

This has *finally* been confirmed, in the season 11 episode "Don't Call me
Shurley."

> **Chuck:** Oh, I'm sorry, I always forget: people can't see me unless I want them to see me. It's very confusing. Here: *[presents Metatron with a pair of Wayfarer sunglasses]* visual aid. Put these on, they'll help. Go on, just do it; it's a whole thing.
>
> *[Metatron puts on the glasses. Chuck taps his finger and is replaced with a bliding flash of light as a heavenly chorus sings]*
>
> **Metatron:** You...God!
>
> <sup>*Supernatural* Season 11 Episode 20: "Don't Call me Shurley"</sup>

### The Road So Far

This was one of the more popular fan theories.

At a [2011 JusInBelloCon panel](https://youtu.be/Ni7uidj9Rx8?t=57s), Rob Benedict (who played Chuck/Carver) pretty much confirmed that his character *was* God:

**Transcript**

> **Audience member:** I was wondering, if you are the God for real, on *Supernatural*, how does it feel?
>
> **Benedict:** It feels awesome. To be all-knowing, it's awesome. No, you know, the funny thing is: I didn't know that I was God, and then they sent me the script, and I read it, and I thought "Oh, I'm wearing white; alright." And then I get up there and the crew - the people who work on the show - are all going "So, hey; God, huh?" And I said "Am I? *[undecipherable]* God? Okay." And then Eric [Kripke] called me after the episode, and he's like "So how did it feel to be God?"

However, in a [2010 interview](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5543025/supernaturals-showrunner-sera-gamble-talks-about-god-and-endings) following "Swan Song" airing, producer Sera Gamble refused to confirm or deny:

> **When I talked to you guys at Comic-Con back in the mists of time, [then-showrunner Eric] Kripke mentioned that we'd be meeting God this season. Does that mean we actually did meet God, and now we're left guessing about who it was (Chuck, Crowley, Joshua, etc.)? Or did you guys decide to leave God out of the picture?**
>
> I love a good God debate, so it's nice to hear we got one going this season. We purposely left a bit of room for interpretation. Although many of your readers probably just read that sentence and rolled their eyes because they feel like we made it all very obvious by the end.
>
> **Nobody thought it was obvious! Do you mean Chuck is the obvious answer, or that you really did leave it open?**
>
> Don't ask me to squish the God debate! How many TV shows can say their fans are talking about THAT stuff?

Comment: I think the edit part should be at the end. Because reading the second part doesn't feel quite as awesome if you read the first part first. Putting the _confirmation_ at the end builds the tension in the answer, but maybe i'm being overdramatic.